# Disabled Items Showing in Listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, listbox

I have a `ListBox` that is bound to a `TabControl`. Some of the `TabItems` inside this (`TabControl`) are hidden/disabled then become visible/enabled when I open a file.

My issue is that these hidden/disabled items are still visible in my ListBox. Can someone help me with regards as to why this is happening?

**TabControl XAML**

```
<TabControl Height="Auto" x:Name="tabControl" Width="Auto" 
            Padding="0" Margin="3" DataContext="{Binding}">
    <TabItem Header="StartPage" x:Name="StartTab" Foreground="White" Height="25">
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="DragDrop" x:Name="DragDropTab" Foreground="White" 
             Height="25" IsEnabled="False" Visibility="Hidden">
        <Image Height="Auto" x:Name="DragImage" Stretch="Fill" Width="Auto" />
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Text" x:Name="TextTab" Foreground="White" 
             Height="25" IsEnabled="False" Visibility="Hidden" >
        <Grid>
            <cbox:SyntaxHighlightBox Height="Auto" x:Name="HighlightText" 
                  Width="Auto" Text="" AcceptsTab="True" AcceptsReturn="True" 
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" />
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

**ListBox XAML**

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items, ElementName=tabControl}" 
         x:Name="ShowOpenTabs" >
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" 
               BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="OpenOnClick"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Perhaps you might show your current code for binding the ListBox's ItemsSource to the TabControl's TabItem so that people can consider how best to add the filter that you want? Are the tabs dynamically inserted/deleted? Are they constantly changing their enabled/visible state?

Comment: Surely! Added the XAML for both TabControl and ListBox. My goal is to just show open items similiarly to Visual Studio "Solution Explorer". Yes, users can click the "X" on the tabitem to hide and then just click on it in the project explorer window to re-enable.

Comment: Disabled != Invisible (just an FYI since you are using the terms interchangeably).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the ListBox item visibility to the tabcontrol item visibility

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" Visibility="{Binding Path=Visibility}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: You may need to change the tabitem visibility to Collapsed to make the list item work properly (or use a binding converter to map Hidden to Collapsed)